# Where should i write db_select() from foreach loop so that it will reduce performance issue?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, drupal

i have been working on performance improvement in drupal for that i wanted to remove db_select() query which is inside foreach loop to improve performace.
here i am adding my code

```
foreach( $order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $line_item ) {
      $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item['line_item_id']);
      $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product['und'][0]  ['product_id']);
      $stock = $product->commerce_stock['und'][0]['value'];

      $query = db_select('commerce_order', 'c');
      $query->join('commerce_line_item', 'l', 'c.order_id = l.order_id');
      $query->addExpression('SUM(quantity)', 'quantity');
      $query->condition('l.line_item_label', $product->sku, '=');
      $query->condition('c.status', 'completed', '<>');
      $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
      $quantity = $result['quantity'];
      if ( ($stock > 0) && ($quantity > $stock) ) {
        $num_updated = db_update('commerce_order')
                       ->fields(array(
                        'status' => 'manufacturer'
                       ))
                       ->condition('order_id', arg(1), '=')
                       ->execute();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, move it out of the loop. Do you have any real question?

Comment: I believe the question is how to move the query out of the loop.

Comment: yes this is real question

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple queries to the DB in the loop that could be moved.

Each call to `commerce_ENTITY_TYPE_load` is a DB access. You should use the `commerce_ENTITY_TYPE_load_multiple` function. This imply collecting all the needed object in arrays, indexed by their respective IDs, which requires some basic boiler plate code.

```
// Collect line item IDs (indexed by delta);
$line_item_ids = array_map(function ($line_item) {
  return $line_item['line_item_id'];
}, field_get_items('commerce_order', $oder, 'commerce_line_items'));
// Get line items, indexed by IDs.
$line_items = commerce_line_items_load_multiple($line_item_ids);

// Collect product IDs, indexed by line item IDs.
$product_ids = array_map(function ($line_item) {
  return field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'commerce_product')[0]['product_id'];
}, $line_items);
// Get products, indexed by IDs.
$products = commerce_product_load_multiple($product_ids);
```

The custom select query is used to retrieve the quantity of a line item matching the SKU of the product for the line item. And you already loaded all the line items and product as entities. So there is no need for more database query and usage of the SKU. Also, since the query update the order itself once a line item with quantity > stock is found, you can break the loop for the first item which does.

```
foreach ($line_items as $line_item_id => $line_item) {
  $product = $products[$products_ids[$line_item_id]];
  $stock = field_get_items('commerce_product', $product, 'commerce_stock')[0]['value'];
  $quantity = $line_item->quantity;
  if (($stock > 0) && ($quantity > $stock)) {
    $num_updated = db_update('commerce_order')
      ->fields(array(
        'status' => 'manufacturer'
      ))
      ->condition('order_id', $order->order_id)
      ->execute();
    break;
  }
}
```